# Call an alert box automatically when the webpage reloads using an extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

In my Chrome Extension, I want that when the URL is reloaded then an alert box will appear, but it does not work

Here is the manifest:

```json
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Sample Extension",
    "description": "Sample Chrome Extension",
    "version": "1.0",
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
    },
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png",
        "default_title": "That's extension",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "permissions":[
        "http://translate.google.hu/*", "tabs"
    ]
}
```

`background.js`:

```js
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId,changeInfo,tab) {
    if (tab.url.indexOf("http://translate.google.hu/") > -1 && 
            changeInfo.url == "undefined") {
        window.alert('test')
    }
});
```

Comment: @livibetter It's always better to add a language tag instead of language markup if the question is definitely about one language. It will enable syntax highlight for answers too.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var object = {};
if(object.something == "undefined") {
  alert("True");
} else {
  alert("False"); 
}
```

You are trying to see if something is undefined by comparing it to a string saying "undefined". That does not work.

The proper way is to check the type:

```
if(typeof changeInfo.url == "undefined") { /* ... */ }
```

The quick and dirty way is to check the truth value: any non-empty string is true and `undefined` is false:

```
if(changeInfo.url) { /* ... */ }
```

Comment: What are the advantages of using typeof changeInfo.url == "undefined" over changeInfo.url == undefined ?